# How to change trailing numbers to incrementing number

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm using ArchLinux 4.1.6-1 and bash 4.3.

I need to tidy up a pile of programs in 200+ industrial robots and so trying to automate the leg work.

I can strip a file down to a just a list of coordinate references in the same order as the original file with mix of `bash`, `sed`, `head`, `tail` etc, like this:

```
via15
via25
via35
via3
via4
via5
p0584_62284
via43
```

I need to change the trailing numbers on lines containing `via` to incremented series of numbers starting at 1:

```
via1
via2
via3
via4
via5
via6
p0584_62284
via7
```

I'm a robot programmer and I can just manage simple `sed` regex, but with `awk`, I'm like a fish on a bicycle.

Comment: Edit: the strings are each on a new line

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '/via/{$0="via" ++n};1' file
via1
via2
via3
via4
via5
via6
p0584_62284
via7
```

#### How it works

- `/via/{$0="via" ++n}`

  If the line contains `via`, the replace it with "via" followed by `n`.  The leading `++` causes `n` to be incremented before each time this is done.  `$0` is how awk refers the line as a whole.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print the line.

  In detail, `1` is a condition and it evaluates to true.  Since no action is specified, the default action is performed which is to print the line: `print $0`.  Thus a lone `1` is shorthand for print the line.

#### More selective approach

Is it possible that the three letters `via` might appear on lines that we do *not* want to change?  If so, we should be more selective about which lines we change.  If we want to change only lines that start with `via` and on which `via` is followed only by numbers, then, as suggested by NeronLeVelu in the comments, we should use a more restrictive regex such as `^via[0-9]+$`.  In that case:

```
awk '/^via[0-9]+$/{$0="via" ++n};1' file
```

Comment: just maybe `/^via[0-9]+$/ ...` in case of

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Good point.  I added that regex to the answer.